# Extjs 4.1.1 - Submitting info from a extjs when it must include non-extjs form data

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a page partially using straight HTML and partially making use of the Extjs framework. The page contains a regular HTML submit button that submits a basic HTML form. I would like the submit button to submit the values on the form like it does already, but I would also like to include a value contained in a Extjs Grid on the page with the form submission.

Comment: This guy is doing something similar, might need to change the code after the e.preventDefault() to an Ext.Ajax.request() though.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450368/ajax-form-submission-using-extjs-and-asp-net-mvc

Comment: sorry not clear enough to answer